# Setting up data contexts in Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I was after some advice please on the best way to set up data contexts for a MongoDB database with Iron Router.

To explain I'm working on a fairly basic film reviews project, and deployed to Modulus at http://reviews-48062.onmodulus.net/

This returns a list of reviews, but would like to use routes to create other pages. I've installed Iron Router locally and have a local MongoDB collection (called tasks) with some data in it.

Have re-written some code to include routing information. This works successfully in displaying the routes, but doesn't seem to pull in any data into the {{each}} statement.

My JS code is as follows:

```
// define Mongodb collection

Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

// set up home route and database query

Router.route('/', function () {
this.render('Home', {
tasks: function () { return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {title: 1}, limit: 10}); }
});
});

// define routes
Router.route('/one');

Router.route('/two');

Router.route('/three');
```

The HTML code is:

```
<head>
<title>Iron router sandbox</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="Home">
{{> Nav}}

<h1>Home</h1>

<p>This is a test</p>
{{#each tasks}}
<li>
<strong>{{title}}</strong>
<p>Directed by {{director}}</p>
<p>{{review}}</p>
<p>Available on: {{format}}</p>
</li>
{{/each}}
</template>

<template name="One">
{{> Nav}}

<h1>Page One</h1>
<p>Some more text.</p>
</template>

<template name="Two">
{{> Nav}}

<h1>Page Two</h1>
<p>A bit more text.</p>
</template>

<template name="Three">
{{> Nav}}

<h1>Page Three</h1>
<p>Even more text.</p>
</template>

<template name="Nav">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/one">Page One</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/two">Page Two</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/three">Page Three</a>
</li>
</ul>
</template>
```

My understanding is that the data context is set up for the "Home" template, so not sure what's wrong with the code.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: In http://reviews-48062.onmodulus.net/ it seems to work. Is it something different than your code?

Answer (score 0):

`tasks` is not a valid property to send to that object.  You need to set the data context for IronRouter using `data` instead.  Change `tasks` to `data`, then set up a helper on your template to get tasks data:

```
Template.Home.helpers({
    tasks() {
        return Tasks.find({}, {sort: {title: 1}, limit: 10});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Stephen. I've set the helper now and it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a data context with i-r but it needs to be named `data`:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
  data: function () {
    return { tasks: Tasks.find({}, {sort: {title: 1}, limit: 10}); } };
  });
});
```

This will return a data context to your template and then the `tasks` key will contain a cursor of tasks.